# SQL - multiple queries or one join

Tags: sql, join

lets say here is my DB structure

```
TableA
{
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) primary key,
    [Title] varchar (50) NOT NULL,
    [Details] varchar(50) NOT NULL
}

TableB:
{
    [ID] INT foreign key references [TableA] ([ID])
    [AvailableTime] DATETIME NOT NULL
}

TableC:
{
[ID] INT foreign key references [TableA] ([ID])
[AvailableLocation] varchar(50) NOT NULL
}
```

I need all the columns from Table A as well as a list of AvailableTimes from Table B for a particular ID

which the result should look like : new object (id, title, details, List availableTime);

there could be multiple available time for one ID. Performance wise and speed wise would it be better if I do two separate queries to retrieve those information or do a join and then loop thru the list twice.
I.E.

```
select * from TableA where ID = 1;
select * from TableB where ID = 1;
select * from TableC where ID = 1;
```

...

OR

```
select * from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.ID = TableB.ID inner join TableC on TableA.ID = TableC.ID where ID = 1
List<DateTime> availableTime = new List<DateTime>();
foreach(DataRow row in resultTable.Rows)
{
    if (!availableTime.Contains((DateTime) row["AvailableTime"]))
        availableTime.Add((DateTime) row["AvailableTime"]);
}

foreach(DataRow row in resultTable.Rows)
{
    if (!availableLocation.Contains((string) row["AvailableTime"]))
        availableLocation.Add((string) row["AvailableLocation"]);
}
return new object ( id, resultTable.Rows[1], resultTable.Rows[2], availableTime,  availableLocation);
```

I am doing this on a server (ASP.NET) and the server is responsible for both running the query and processing the data before it sends out to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to provide the correct answer and help if you could share your table schema

Comment: run both queries and see which performs better. Sometimes running two simple queries is better than one complex query. It all depends, and it is difficult to say with the information given. You have to test it.

Comment: You'll need to do processing on the client in either case to get a "tree" out of SQL. SQL returns *tabular* data. In C# such a transformation (while keeping a single query) is trivial with LINQ.

Comment: question updated. I am doing this on the server side and I am wondering which way would be better for the server. I do not know how many rows to expect for the second query, which way would be better if the second query 1. returns small amount of rows 2. large amount of rows?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` should be fine. Just avoid `SELECT *` and choose only the columns you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do processing on the client in either case to get a "tree" out of SQL. SQL returns *tabular* data which is de-normalized.

---

> Performance wise and speed wise, would it be better if I do two separate queries to retrieve those information or do a join and then loop through the list twice?

*Usually*, doing the join in SQL is faster and easier. Manually looping SQL selects in code is one way to *effectively make the RA useless* as any hash/merge join is turned into "nested loops".

Since C# supports such a transformation trivially with LINQ, it is my "first preference" - well, first after using a bonafide LINQ-to-Database provider - to deal with this situation.

Take the query (where I've renamed "id" for sanity):

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.title, i.details, t.available_time
FROM items i 
JOIN times t ON t.item_id = i.item_id
```

The Joined form will return a result-set of `(item_id, title, details, available_time)`.

Now to read the query result it into a collection of "readItems" such that the type conforms to `IEnumerable<{of the same fields as above}>` and then rebuild the tree structure from the data.

```cs
var items = readItems
    // The group by "re-normalize" on the key and the selector
    // is still key on RS - as the title/details are FDs on item_id
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.item_id, i.title, i.details })
    .Select(g => new ItemWithTimes {
        ItemId = g.Key.item_id,
        Title = g.Key.title,
        Details = g.Key.details,
        // capture collected data
        AvailableTimes = g,
    });
```

Of course, if you're using a LINQ-to-SQL/EF provider (instead of the imagined LINQ-to-Objects above) then you can skip manually going through the flat "readItems" result-set.

---

There are some exceptions, generally with *hyper de-normalized* result-sets, where multiple queries may be more appropriate - this usually affects *really deep* trees or when "large" columns are duplicated.

Also, some databases like SQL Server supports XML, which can deal with hyper de-normalized result-sets (aka trees) without needing to go through the flat tabular result-set.

In any case, you'll know you need to do this when the time comes - and keeping a clean DAL (instead of leaking access all over the place) will make changing implementations relatively trivial.

Comment: can I still do the same thing if I have a 3rd table which I want a list of data for

Comment: @Steve Sure [you would just further group the group values on the appropriate key for them], but then you're entering the realm of "deep" trees and trading more server efficiency (the RA join) for less client efficiency (although the group-by is probably hash-join operation). There is some tipping point - and maintenance point. I normally just let LINQ2SQL do all the hard work for me. Honestly, in many cases, it just doesn't matter - and where it does, that's what I focus on "optimizing".

Comment: what if the server has to process the data too, since I am working on an asp.net project

Comment: Let it. Not sure what the problem is - in any case, I suspect your model is incorrect. Available location/time should likely be a pairing (unless every location is available at the same time or not at all).

Comment: Which way would be better for the server? I know 2nd way would be better if I can just grab the data and send it to the user to process. but the first way seem to be easier for the server to process if we don't care about the DB server

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't need a `join` at all:

```
select PropertyA
from tableA
where id = XXX
union all
select PropertyC
from tableB
where id = XXX;
```

If you want to remove duplicates, change `union all` to `union`.

Comment: right, union if fine too. But I still want to know which one performs better. 2 queries or 1

Comment: @Steve . . . Two queries incur the overhead of preparing the queries, compiling them, and passing them back and forth into the database.  One query should perform better.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple join query will be something like this

```
Select A.*, B.AvailableTime 
from TableA A 
inner join TableB B on A.ID=B.ID
```

But you can avoid duplicate by using concatenating to a single comma separate string

```
select A.*, ( SELECT ', ' + B.AvailableTime 
       FROM TableB B
       WHERE A.ID=B.ID 
       FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Timings
from TableA A
```

But, it depends on your requirements which one suits you better.

Comment: I am more concerned about performance and speed rather than the query itself

Comment: performance wise instead of sending two result sets to the application and join there, sending single resultset would obviously be faster. if the resultset has no duplicate, then it would save overhead of sending bigger data. try second query.